# GET request with JSON body in SugarCRM

Tags: json, http, get, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM rest API, and according to the [documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_8.0/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/Endpoints/module_GET/), to get a set of records, I have to use `/<module> GET` endpoint and pass JSON in the body to filter the query.

First, is it even possible to have a body in a GET request ?

and how can I build this kind of request then ?

I'm using postman and tried to pass parameters as query strings but it's not possible though.

Comment: Can you share one of the query strings you tried please. So that we can see if something is wrong with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you have to put everything in the query string, which might look different to what you'd expect.

Example for a request to `/Users`:

```
{
    max_num: 100,
    fields: ["first_name", "last_name"],
    filter: [
        {"user_name":"admin"}
        {"status":"Active"}
    ]
}
```

Written as query string this request will look like this:

`/rest/v10/Users?max_num=100&fields=first_name,last_name&filter[0][user_name]=admin&filter[1][status]=Active`

Observations regarding the query string format:

- There is no `{` or `}`, the values of the request object are placed directly in the query string
- Key-Value pairs are assigned with `=`, and separated by `&` (instead of `:` and `,`)
- There are no `"` or `'` quotes at all, strings are written without those
- An array of values (here: `fields`) is just one assignment with all values separated by `,`
- An array of objects (here: `filter`) has one Key-Value pair per bottom value and uses `[` and `]` to indicate the "path" to each value. Using 0-based numerical indices for arrays

**Notes**

- Keep in mind there are length limits to URL incl. query string. E.g. 4096 bytes/chars for Apache 2, if I remember correctly. If you have to send very elaborate requests, you might want to use `POST /rest/v10/<module>/filter` instead.
- URL-escaped (usually not necessary) the example filter would look like this:
  `/rest/v10/Users?max_num%3D100%26fields%3Dfirst_name%2Clast_name%26filter%5B0%5D%5Buser_name%5D%3Dadmin%26filter%5B1%5D%5Bstatus%5D%3DActive`